# select autocomplete set value ngModel programmatically on edit form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms, angular9, ngmodel

When I get to the edit form I need to prefill the values to the form.

the create form works fine and the values are submitted fine,

HTML:

```
<!-- customers-->
<div class="col-md-6">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Customers"
           i18n-placeholder="customerInput"
           aria-label="customers"
           matInput
           required
           [name]="'customerId'"
           (focus)="getCustomers(searchedCustomer)"
           [ngModel]="contractInterface.customerName"
           (ngModelChange)="customerOnChange($event)"
           [matAutocomplete]="autoCustomer">
    <mat-autocomplete #autoCustomer="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="customerCollectionDisplayFn">

      <mat-option *ngIf="customerloading"><span [ngTemplateOutlet]="loading"></span></mat-option>

      <ng-container *ngIf="!customerloading">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customerList" [value]="customer">
          {{ customer.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I use the `[displayWith]="customerCollectionDisplayFn"` to display the value to the input

TS:

```
  customerCollectionDisplayFn(customer?) {
return customer?.name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So What I did I just changed the ngModel `[ngModel]="customer"` then

```
  private getContractDetails(id: number) {

    this.contractService.loadContractDetails(id)
      .subscribe( (rez: Contract) => {
        // add value to customer input
        this.customer.name = rez.customerName; // <-- this
```

and it got up..

--- BONUS ---

for a select input, this worked

HTML:

```
 <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label i18n="@@typeInput">Type</mat-label>
        <mat-select
          name="typeId"
          [ngModel]="typesVal" // <--- this
          (ngModelChange)="setContractType($event)"
          #item="ngModel">
          <mat-option *ngIf="isLoadingTypes"><span [ngTemplateOutlet]="loading"></span></mat-option>
          <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoadingTypes">
            <mat-option>None</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of contractTypeList" [value]="item">{{ item.name }}</mat-option>
          </ng-container>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

the CODE

`this.typesVal = this.contractTypeList.find(x => x.id === rez.typeId);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    1. When you click the "Edit Form" Button you have to gather the persisted 
information for the form inputs fields. this might be from localstorage or from 
http request via angular service ([Angular Tutorial Http Server][1]) like in 
section --> "app/config/config.service.ts (getConfig v.1)".


    2. then create an empty "contractInterface" property in your component and 
update it after you got the infos from localstorage or http request


    like ...
    contractInterface: any = {};

    or ...
    contractInterface: BlaInterface = new BlaInterface();

    later...

    loadMyFormValues() {
      this.myFormService.myGetFormValuesFn()
        .subscribe((contractInterface: any) 
        => this.contractInterface = contractInterface);
    }


      [1]: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server
```

ps: using the word interface in your variable name might be confusing. personally, I prefer avoiding it. also in the interface name itself if applicable.

Comment: This does not answer my question, I asked for how to get the data into the input. I am already filling the interface with data from the API. but the input from angular-material is making problems.